# How to disable copy&paste popup button?

Tags: microsoft-word

Whenever I paste something copied before I get this button popping up: [image] Most of the time it is exactly at the wrong spot and I have to press "Esc" to hide it before I can read my text under it again.

Is there any way to completely disable this popup button?

Answer (score 1):

The button can be disabled under File/Options/Advanced:

[image]